# Organisaing metric storage in Graphite?

Tags: graphite

How can I get my metrics to be saved at the root level. Currently been saved under the stats hierarchy (see [graphite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe1wJ.png))
Want to save under the top level(Graphite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your using statsd with the graphite.js backend.

In the code is setup to prefix the metrics with **stats.** if no globalprefix is provided during the init()

https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/backends/graphite.js

```
line 180: globalPrefix  = globalPrefix !== undefined ? globalPrefix : "stats";
```

You will need to change how your calling the init() to offer it a blank gobalPrefix.

**OR**

You would need to alter the backend in order to stop is prefix all your statsd metrics with **stats.**

Comment: Prathan's answer should be marked as correct. You just need to include the *prefix options under the 'graphite' key.

Answer (score 8):

Add these settings to your statsd configuration file (possibly something like `/etc/statsd.js`)

```
{
  ...(unrelated options)...
, graphite: {
    legacyNamespace: false
  , globalPrefix:  ""
  , prefixCounter: ""
  , prefixTimer:   ""
  , prefixGauge:   ""
  , prefixSet:     ""
  }
}
```